# Set EEPROM to initial values when flashing ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, eeprom

I have a variable `uint8_t a_ram` which needs to be initialized from the EEPROM variable `a_eeprom` when the ESP boots up. Whenever `a_ram` changes, the new value has to be stored to the EEPROM (`a_eeprom`), so that the ESP will initialize `a_ram` to this new value after the next reboot.

The problem I have is to understand, how the value of `a_eeprom` can be initialized for **the very first boot**. If `a_eeprom` has not been set before (that means, that `a_ram` has not been stored to EEPROM yet), my variable will be initialized to `0`, which must not be the case.

I could introduce an extra variable to the EEPROM (kind of a flag), which tells me whether `a_ram` has been stored to EEPROM or not and only initialize `a_ram` to `a_eeprom` if that is the case. But as I don't want to spend this memory if it isn't neccessary, I'd like to know if there is a possibility to set an EEPROM value when flashing the ESP.
Btw, I'm using the arduino IDE.

Comment: First you should probably research how EEPROM is *approximately emulated* on a system that doesn't actually have any.

Comment: it is written to flash.to location after SPIFS

Comment: @Juraj unfortunately I'm not very familiar with this topic. Could you give me a hint about what I should update myself if I did not understand your comment? ;)

Comment: @ChrisStratton as far as I understand the ESP, it has an EEPROM onboard and does not only emulate it

Comment: @SimSon - you are mistaken.  The ESP8266 has no on-chip EEPROM, and most *boards* pair it with an SPI flash, not an EEPROM.

Comment: I was answering Chris. read the docs http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/libraries.html#eeprom